# SQL Server How to group rows when some columns are nulls

Tags: sql-server

I want to know how to group rows in SQL Server when columns are nulls, for example.

```
ID   |col1 |col2      |col3|col4 |col5      |col6|col4 |col5      |col6|col7      |
-----|-----|----------|----|-----|----------|----|-----|----------|----|----------|
1256 |2    |2018-01-01|CP  |     |          |    |     |          |    |2018-01-01|
1256 |     |          |    |3    |2018-01-02|CR  |     |          |    |2018-01-02|
1256 |     |          |    |     |          |    |4    |2018-01-03|CA  |2018-01-03|
```

and the result is this

```
ID   |col1 |col2      |col3|col4 |col5      |col6|col4 |col5      |col6|

-----|-----|----------|----|-----|----------|----|-----|----------|----|
1256 |2    |2018-01-01|CP  |3    |2018-01-02|CR  |4    |2018-01-03|CA  |
```

Comment: Use aggregate functions (like max/min in this instance) and group by ID.

Comment: Ok, let me try.

Comment: I used top 1 on a internal subquery. For each col* is a subquery. It does work with max/min too?

Comment: what query u are using? You can easily group by Id and take max/min for each column.

Comment: well my query result is looped by col 7, but exist some condition that could group rows and skipped the col7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write query like follwong (Only few columns included for sample). It will give you desired output.

```
    WITH MyTable as (
    select * from (values 
        (1256 , 2 ,   getdate(),'CP',NULL,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        ,(1256,  null ,   null,NULL,3,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        ,(1256,  null ,   null,NULL,NULL,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))

    ) t (Id, Col1  , Col2,Col3,Col4,Col7)
  )


 SELECT DISTINCT id, 
            C1.col1, 
            C2.col2, 
            C3.col3, 
            C4.col4 
FROM   mytable MT 
   OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 col1 
                FROM   mytable I 
                WHERE  I.id = MT.id 
                       AND col1 IS NOT NULL)C1 
   OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 col2 
                FROM   mytable I 
                WHERE  I.id = MT.id 
                       AND col2 IS NOT NULL)C2 
   OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 col3 
                FROM   mytable I 
                WHERE  I.id = MT.id 
                       AND col3 IS NOT NULL)C3 
   OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 col4 
                FROM   mytable I 
                WHERE  I.id = MT.id 
                       AND col4 IS NOT NULL)C4
```

**Another way of doing this**

```
WITH MyTable as (
    select * from (values 
        (1256 , 2 ,   getdate(),'CP',NULL,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        ,(1256,  null ,   null,NULL,3,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        ,(1256,  null ,   null,NULL,NULL,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))

    ) t (Id, Col1  , Col2,Col3,Col4,Col7)
)


SELECT DISTINCT ID 
,(SELECT TOP 1 Col1 from MyTable Where Id = MT.Id AND Col1 IS NOT NULL ) AS Col1
,(SELECT TOP 1 Col2 from MyTable Where Id = MT.Id AND Col2 IS NOT NULL ) AS Col2
,(SELECT TOP 1 Col3 from MyTable Where Id = MT.Id AND Col3 IS NOT NULL ) AS Col3
,(SELECT TOP 1 Col4 from MyTable Where Id = MT.Id AND Col4 IS NOT NULL ) AS Col4

FROM MyTable MT
```

**Output**

```
ID     Col1 COL2                     Col3     Col4
1256    2   2018-02-06 07:26:49.260  CP        3
```

Comment: Great.. pleas accept the answer if resolved your query

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's work with max/min aggregated on subquery, the way that i had to found is (using the query create by @PSK)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID 
,max(MT.col1) AS Col1
,max(MT.col2) AS Col2
,max(MT.col3) AS Col3
,max(MT.col4) AS Col4

FROM 
(
    select * from (values 
        (1256 , 2 ,   getdate(),'CP',NULL,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        ,(1256,  null ,   null,NULL,3,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        ,(1256,  null ,   null,NULL,NULL,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))

    ) t (Id, Col1  , Col2,Col3,Col4,Col7)
  ) AS MT
GROUP by
ID
```

and the result its the same